# Combinatorics puzzle

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, puzzle

I am having a problem dealing with following topic:

lets say we have set of numbers `n = [ 1 2 2 3 ]` and we want be able to get all two-elementary combinations out of that(1.) and remove all repetitions(2.).

1.) Using combination formula `n!/(k!  (n - k)!)` we end up having 6 pairs

```
([1 2], [1 2], [1 3], [2 2], [2 3], [2 3])
```

2.) Now I do not know how to compute amount of repetitions I need to get rid of `([1 2], [2 3])` to get clean set of 4 elements `([1 2], [1 3], [2 2], [2 3])`.

Can someone explain me how to deal with these problems, please? I need to learn how algorithm works so I can create different size of subgroups from elements that may repeat.

P.S. it is important to result with a set of unique subgroups, not a quantity of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First count/enumerate all unordered pairs of *different* elements. That requires just knowing how many different elements that are in your original set.

Then take all the possible pairs of two *identical* elements. That's just a matter of checking which of your original elements have more than one copy.

Note that as soon as one of the original elements has *two* copies, adding more copies of it makes no difference.